# How to put a value into a char * with an index

Tags: c

I have a function that gets char * and I want to print the additional value in each interaction
For example:
hello

h

he

hel

hell

hello

The problem is that I have a memory impairment and writing
Exception thrown at 0x7B18F791 (ucrtbased.dll) in workhome4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000069.

```
void addSpaceCheck(char* word)
{
    char* stringOne = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
                    
            strcat(stringOne, word[i]);
    
                    
                printf("%s", stringOne);
            }
    
        }
}
```

Comment: Show where `word` is defined. Additionally, you never initialized `stringOne`, so there's no gaurantee it ends with a null-terminator (Try `calloc` or using a more appropriately-bounded size and setting the end)

Comment: look at now I edit this

Comment: You may find it easier to have one string, `strlen`, and then "%.*s" to just print out a section of it.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat(stringOne, word[i]);` causes the problem in this case. `strcat` expects a NUL terminated string. `stringOne` is allocated but does not contain any useful data. Optionally, you could use `calloc()` to zero out the allocated block of memory. In any case, `strcat(stringOne, word[i]);` will not do what you think because the second argument is a `char`.

You could do this:

```
void addSpaceCheck(char* word)
{
    char* stringOne = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word) - 1; i++) {
                stringOne[i] = word[i];
                stringOne[i + 1] = '\0';
                printf("%s", stringOne);
            }
    
        }
}
```

Comment: So what can i replace the strcat?

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @yovelde Please consider accepting an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strcat()` without adding a string terminator first.

Nor can you hope that `strcat()` can add a single character like that.

Instead I suggest

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
    stringOne[i] = word[i]; 
    stringOne[i+1] = '\0';
    printf("%s ", stringOne);
}
```

This will ouput

```
H He Hel Hell Hello
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Please show your thanks by *upvoting* helpful answers, and *accepting* the best in your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` requires `char *` as second parameter not `char`

if you want to use `strcat` you need to pass a valid C string as second parameter

```
void addSpaceCheck1(char* word)
{
    size_t length = strlen(word);
    char* stringOne = malloc(length + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {            
        strcat(stringOne, (char[]){word[i], 0});
        printf("%s ", stringOne);
    }
    free(stringOne);
}
```

But it makes a little sense to use this very heavy function. You can simply assign the char and terminate the string.

```
void addSpaceCheck(char* word)
{
    size_t length = strlen(word);
    char* stringOne = malloc(length + 1);

    for(size_t index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        stringOne[index] = word[index];
        stringOne[index + 1] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", stringOne);
    }
    free(stringOne);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the function is only to print, you don't need another string to do it.
You can use printf directly with the format `%.*s` that allows you to specify the (maximum) number of characters printed:

```
void addSpaceCheck(const char *word) // const if not modified
{
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.*s\n", i+1, word);
    }
}
```